# InfoBubble open specific tab

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, infobubble

In JavaScript, I found this neat little plugin for the google maps API v3, called [InfoBubble](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobubble/examples/example.html). It does a GREAT job at making it easy to have highly customized Info Windows. What I can't seem to find in there though is how to open a specific tab through a function call and not a click on a tab button. I tried setTabActive(index) which was one of the functions of the plugin but it doesn't seem to work. Am I missing something obvious or is it more than just digging for the right function in the js file?

For reference, here's my code:

```
var center = new google.maps.LatLng(//...getting some lat/lng coords...
var bubble = new InfoBubble(
{
    map: motherMap,
    position: center,
    minHeight: 250,
    maxHeight: 250,
    minWidth: 250,
    maxWidth: 250,
    tabClassName: "contentTab",
    padding: 3
});

//...creating tabs, getting which tab should be opened, setting the value of tabToShow and so on...

//at this point I've checked with console.out() and tabToShow is a number 0-2
bubble.setTabActive(tabToShow);
```

Even with that code, the first tab is opened every time. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**: I actually fixed the problem myself right after posting here... After looking at the code closer I noticed the author, for whatever reason, uses numbering beginning at 1 instead of 0. It's a nice plugin but definitely needs some documentation...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the tab is open (you can check with the isOpen() method).

If you want, you can modify InfoBubble.prototype.open to open a specific tab:

```
  window.setTimeout(function() {
         that.open_(opt_map, opt_anchor);
         that.setTabActive(_defaultTab);        
  }, 0);
```